# Are there any copy and pastable web form elements for use in word (for documentation/mockups)

Tags: documentation

Are there any copy and pastable web form elements for use in word 
(for documentation/mockups etc)

Just need to quickly show a layout examples of web forms to send to clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for Word, but for Photoshop: [Web Browser Elements](http://www.designerstoolbox.com/designresources/elements/) from Designers Toolbox.

Or: [Form Elements](http://www.webdesignerstoolkit.com/forms.php) from Webdesigners Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

You can find examples over on the **w3schools** website; just check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). You can just copy-paste from the webpage straight into Word.